# How to do you make colored bullet points with python-docx?

Tags: colors, formatting, python-docx

I am wondering if it is possible to set the bullet point color in python-docx  (style= List Bullet) without changing the font color? 
I know its possible using word but I can't find the attribute to do this via code.
Thanks